# Modify stored procedure functionality is outputting the Alter stmt as dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Just recently my SSMS changed and it's driving me crazy. Normally when you right click on a stored procedure and select "Modify", it outputs the stored procedure code as a bunch of SQL statements.

Starting yesterday, mine now outputs a giant `sp_executesql` statement (see screenshot). What setting controls this??  Using v 18.12.1

[image]

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: v 18.12.1 - added to the question

Comment: The reason the existence check makes a difference is because you can't start a new batch inside an `IF` so the `CREATE PROC` needs to be put inside dynamic SQL as CREATE PROC must be the only statement inside the batch/scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of the existence check before the code creation of your procedure setting is enabled.

To control this behavior follow the steps.

1. From the menu option, click "***Tools > Options***".
2. On the left side, expand "***SQL Server Object Explorer***" and choose "***Scripting***"
3. On the right-hand side, under the group "***Object Scripting Options***" change the setting "***Check for object existence***" to false.

[image]

Tested on v18.4

Comment: YES!  Thank you!  Do you automatically get the bounty or do I have to give it to you?

Comment: Thanks.. it will automatically happen I guess.